# Are my friends trying to scam me or help me?

Tags: scams

Some people I know IRL are saying then can make me $10-30k per day, and they need all my bank info including the security questions. They also said that I don't need money in the account. Is this a scam?
What could they possibly do with an empty bank account?

Comment: I'm curious why you used the word "friends" in the title?

Comment: If you suspect a scam, it probably is.

Comment: Also be aware that to give your bank info to someone else is almost certainly a violation of the conditions of your account.

Comment: You should make some new friends and ditch these ones, because they're not your friends.

Comment: Run. Don't look back.

Answer (score 27):

If there was a way that you friends could make  $10-30k and all they needed was an empty a bank account, why aren't they going to every bank in town and opening bank accounts for themselves?  What use are you to them?    Because they need a patsy to take the fall for whatever they have in mind.

And no, this does not pass the sniff test. It's a scam of some sort or an illegal activity such as money laundering.

Answer (score 14):

To answer the part about "What could they possibly do with an empty bank account?", then can do exactly what they do with the fake cheque scam.

They pay something into your account. Based on that they transfer some money from your account to themselves in a non-reversible way. They then reverse the payment into your account (or they made the payment into your account with a fake cheque, which will eventually be discovered and be reversed by the bank).

You are left with an account that has a negative balance, and the bank will come after you for that money.

It's also conceivable that they are using it for money laundering, so moving money in from criminal organizations and moving it out to themselves, or to terrorist organizations. In which case you won't lose any money you will just end up in jail.

And yes, this is so definitely a scam that I would seriously consider reporting this to the police and maybe catching them in the act.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is a scam.

Knowing what they are going to do with your account exactly is less relevant than recognizing their fraudulent intent for what it is, saying no, and possibly cutting ties with them.

The question to ask them or yourself, is, given that they can allegedly make $10-30k *per day*, how come they are not billionaires yet, and why can't they do this with their own account.

Comment: "given that they can make $10-30k per day, how come they are not billionaires yet" Because they haven't been doing it for over 90 years.

Comment: @Kevin So that question would test both their intentions and their math skills. :)

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a scam?

No.  Obviously these people are extremely generous and able to generate between $3,650,000 and $10,950,000 per year with nothing more than your account details but they just can't do it without you!

> What could they possibly do with an empty bank account?

Launder money because it's a ______ scam.

Comment: LOL. Normally I downvote blatantly incorrect answers, but this is too funny. Though I might suggest making it a CW to avoid the banter.

Comment: I don't think sarcasm is helpful in answer because it is so often missed or misinterpreted.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant how about now, lol.

Comment: @quid it's still primarily as sarcastic retort. Like I say, I don't think sarcastic answers are helpful. That's just me though.

Comment: C'mon, let's not sterilize the dialogue :->)

Comment: For the record, I upvoted the original.  This is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a scam. If there was a way to make $10-30k with a bank account, we would all already be doing it.